# Last 5 Page Names User Viewed

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

I'm trying to code the last 5 page names the user viewed on my site and produce it into a list. I'm currently able to get the current page name, but I don't know how to get the previous pages. This is the code I'm using to get the current page name:

```
<?php
    $pageName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    echo $pageName;
?>
```

Comment: Show us what you tried. HAve you tried anything at all?

Comment: You can't get the name of the previous pages (except the last one with `$_SERVER['REFERER']`) so you have to keep track of every pages visited by the user yourself. Have fun.

Answer (score 1):

[PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) should get you going in the right direction.  For example:

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['pages'])) {
    $_SESSION['pages'] = array();
}
if(count($_SESSION['pages']) < 5) {
    $_SESSION['pages'] []  = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
} else {
    echo "Limit reached";
}
print_r($_SESSION['pages']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use [PHP Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) to accomplish this.

So, save the current page name that you want to the sessions variable like so:

```
<?php
    $pageName = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $_SESSION['pageName'] = $pageName;
?>
```

And then continue to save these names.  @Len_D just beat me to the punch with an answer that uses arrays and is likely what you need.